# AttributeError: 'async_generator' object has no attribute 'flatten'

Tags: python, discord.py

Hi i have been getting a Flatten error when i try and run my ticket bot on line 26, not sure how to fix it, any help would be greatly appreciated

the bot runs but doesn't post a message in the channel or deletes the old one, it did before

there are other files to this one, one being the config where the channel id is

````
import discord
import json
import data

# load config
with open("support.json", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    SUPPORT_CONFIG = json.load(f)


async def initialize(client: discord.Client):
    global support_request_channel
    global support_category
    global reaction_msg

    support_request_channel = client.get_channel(
        int(SUPPORT_CONFIG["SUPPORT_REQUEST_CHANNEL"]))
    support_category = client.get_channel(
        int(SUPPORT_CONFIG["SUPPORT_CATEGORY"]))

    if support_category is None or support_request_channel is None:
        print(
            "Unable to find support request channel or category. Please check your config.")
        exit()

    # find reaction message
    msgs = await support_request_channel.history(limit=200, oldest_first=True).flatten()
    client_user_msgs = [m for m in msgs if m.author.id ==
                        client.user.id and len(m.embeds) == 1]

    if len(client_user_msgs) > 0:
        for m in msgs:
            await m.delete()

    # build the support embed
    embed = discord.Embed()
    embed.title = "Request Support"
    embed.description = "Please react with appropriate emoji to start a support ticket.\n\n"
    embed.color = discord.Color.blue()

    # add roles to embed from the config
    for i in SUPPORT_CONFIG["SUPPORT_DATA"]:
        line = "{}: **{}**\n".format(i["emoji"], i["type"])
        embed.description += line

    reaction_msg = await support_request_channel.send(embed=embed)

    # add reactions
    for i in SUPPORT_CONFIG["SUPPORT_DATA"]:
        await reaction_msg.add_reaction(i["emoji"])


async def handle_reaction_add(reaction: discord.Reaction, user: discord.User, client: discord.Client):
    # ignore self reactions
    if user.id == client.user.id or reaction.message.id != reaction_msg.id:
        return

    await reaction.remove(user)

    # find proper roles
    reaction_info = next(
        (i for i in SUPPORT_CONFIG["SUPPORT_DATA"] if i["emoji"] == reaction.emoji), None)

    if reaction_info is None:
        return

    # create permission overwrites for roles
    allowed = discord.PermissionOverwrite(view_channel=True)
    disallowed = discord.PermissionOverwrite(view_channel=False)

    overwrites = {
        support_category.guild.default_role: disallowed,
        user: allowed
    }

    # for welcome support channel welcome msg
    role_pings = []
    for role_id in reaction_info["roles"]:
        role = support_category.guild.get_role(int(role_id))
        if role is None:
            print("Role with ID {} not found. Please check your config.".format(role_id))
            continue
        overwrites[role] = allowed
        role_pings.append("<@&{}>".format(role.id))

    role_pings = ",".join(role_pings)

    sc_name = "support-{}".format(user.name)
    support_channel = await support_category.create_text_channel(name=sc_name, overwrites=overwrites)

    # send message to support channel
    support_welcome_text = reaction_info["welcome_message"].format(
        user.id, role_pings)

    embed = discord.Embed()
    embed.description = "**{}**".format(support_welcome_text)
    embed.color = discord.Color.blue()

    await support_channel.send(embed=embed)

    # save in db
    data.save_support_channel(
        support_channel.id, user.id, reaction_info["type"])
```
````

Comment: `flatten()` is a numpy method as far as I know. Did you define `flatten()` anywhere else in your code?

Comment: Try replacing the code  `xxxx.flatten()` with `list(xxxxx)`.

Comment: Hi thank you for your reply, flatten is only defined the code snippet above no where else

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there was an API change in discord.py and the flatten method is no longer available on the async generator returned by `support_request_channel.history(...)`. Instead, use this code to put the results into a list:

```py
msgs = [msg async for msg in support_request_channel.history(limit=200, oldest_first=True)]
```

The API change is documented [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migrating.html#moving-away-from-custom-asynciterator:%7E:text=AsyncIterator.flatten()).